# call jquery method using scriptmanager in C#

Tags: jquery, scriptmanager

I added a web user control and created a function in jquery at client side named "ButtonClick" on web user control. And calling this method from code behind using ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript  in loop . 
But it runs only one time, while it should run loop times.

Please help me......
Code sample is here

```
  var q = (from p in obj.Pinny_ShowOffer where (p.OfferID == objOffer.OfferID) select p).ToList();
    if (q.Count > 0)
    {
        Rdbtnoffersetup.Items.FindByValue("2").Selected = true;
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "ShowDIv", "ShowDiv(2,2);", true);
        Int32 k = 0;
        for (Int32 i = 0; i < q.Count; i++)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "ButtonClick",
                                                                        "ButtonClick('btn" + q[i].Weekday + "','" + q[i].Weekday + "');", true);
            if (q[i].StartTime == "07:00" && q[i].EndTime == "11:00")
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "select value", "SelectValueoFDropDown('drpStart" + q[i].Weekday + k + "','1');", true);
            }
            k++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's only firing once is because you're duplicating they key `ButtonClick` in your `RegisterStartupScript` call.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx):

> A client script is uniquely identified by its key and its type.
>   Scripts with the **same key and type are considered duplicates**. Only one
>   script with a given type and key pair can be registered with the page.
>   Attempting to register a script that is already registered does not
>   create a duplicate of the script.

---

You could trying something like this instead to keep it unique:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "ButtonClick" + i.toString(),"ButtonClick('btn" + q[i].Weekday + "','" + q[i].Weekday + "');", true);
```